# How to get, edit and save xml content containing nested namespaces?

Tags: xml, xpath, xml-parsing, simplexml, domdocument

Here is my xml file content:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<w:document xmlns:ve="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml">
    <w:body>
        <w:p w:rsidR="00551371" w:rsidRDefault="0010551B" w:rsidP="0010551B">
            <w:pPr>
                <w:jc w:val="center"/>
            </w:pPr>
            <w:r>
                <w:t xml:space="preserve">Hi this is a paragraph with </w:t>
            </w:r>
            <w:r w:rsidRPr="00517389">
                <w:rPr>
                    <w:b/>
                </w:rPr>
                <w:t>default</w:t>
            </w:r>
            <w:r>
                <w:t xml:space="preserve"> text and some wording in it so </w:t>
            </w:r>
        </w:p>
        <w:p w:rsidR="0010551B" w:rsidRDefault="0010551B" w:rsidP="0010551B">
            <w:pPr>
                <w:jc w:val="center"/>
            </w:pPr>
            <w:r>
                <w:t xml:space="preserve">Here is new </w:t>
            </w:r>
            <w:r w:rsidRPr="00517389">
                <w:rPr>
                    <w:u w:val="single"/>
                </w:rPr>
                <w:t>line sentence</w:t>
            </w:r>
            <w:r>
                <w:t xml:space="preserve"> with some text.</w:t>
            </w:r>
        </w:p>
          .
          .
          .
          and so on.
```

Right now i am getting the content of `<w:t>` independently, below is my code:

```
// load the xml into the object
$xml = simplexml_load_file('sample/word/document.xml');

//Use that namespace
$namespaces = $xml->getNameSpaces(true);

$xml->registerXPathNamespace('w', $namespaces['w']);

$nodes = $xml->xpath('/w:document/w:body//w:t');

$i = 1;

foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    echo (string) $node; // prints each node value correctly
    $node->nodeValue = "abc"; // it adds the node instead of replacing
    $i++;
}

$xml->asXML('test.xml');
```

It gives me text of each `w:t` separately, but I want to get w.r.t `<w:p>` mean all the text in all `<w:t>` nodes under single `<W:p>` should be treated as single node.

Like text under first `<w:p>` should return **"Hi this is a paragraph with default text and some wording in it so".**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, rather than using `registerXPathNamespace` and XPath, you can just use the `->children()` method to select a namespace and use normal SimpleXML access methods. In this case you can use `foreach ( $xml->children('w', true)->body->p as $p_node ) ...`

Secondly, there is no `nodeValue` property in SimpleXML (maybe you're thinking of the DOM?). To overwrite an element's content, you just assign to it, e.g. `$node->child = 'abc';`. However, this is a little trickier in the loop because you've got to know which element you're looking at; but you can, for instance, say `$xml->children('w', true)->body->p[0] = 'asd';`

Finally, to combine all the text in the `<w:p>` nodes, you'll need to loop over their `<w:r>` children, which in your example have one `<w:t>` in each. So you end up with a nested loop something like this:

```
foreach ( $sx->children('w', true)->body->p as $p_node ) { 
    $p_content=''; 
    foreach ( $p_node->r as $r_node ) { 
        $p_content .= (string)$r_node->t; 
    } 
    echo $p_content;
}
```